# Getting more padding than supposed

Tags: html, css, padding

I was coding a menu when I noticed that the paddings I gave weren't right.

[image]

As you can see, its not even center aligned. I've tried box-sizing but nothing...

**This is the code I have:**

```
<!-- html -->
<a href="#">LinkedIn</a>


<!-- css -->
a:link, a:visited{
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding: 6px 20px;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 14px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**I'm also using a reset.css,**
[this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/devrafael/pen/jEMMma)

Comment: Try adjusting your `line-height`

Comment: I tried, but still nothing

Comment: can you post more relevant code? or a link? it's hard to tell what's going on from the CSS you provided

Comment: yes sure @jmore009, you may check now

Comment: thanks, to be clear, you're saying that the padding between the words and the edges of the white box are not correct?

Comment: Yes, thats it. You can see the problem on mousehover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to post two images here. The first one is your image from codepen as is

[image]

I took this screenshot into photoshop and measured out the sides so you can see. The boxes on the top are exactly the same height (one was copied form the other) and the boxes on the sides are exactly the same width. So as you can see this isn't a `padding` issue. `Padding` is working just as expected. But something does still look off as you mentioned

Here is the second image:

[image]

In this image I changed your font to plain `"Arial"` and again measured the boxes so you can see. Their exactly the same and line up perfectly. The issue here has nothing to do with your CSS but rather how the `font-family` is being rendered. I have encountered this issue myself with certain fonts. You can possibly play with `line-height` some more or you can always overcompensate the `padding` on the bottom to make up for the difference. Ex: `padding: 6px 20px 7px 20px;`

Comment: In this scenario, if you didn't want o "hack" your css, do you think another font would be a good try?

Comment: certainly, but I wouldn't say overcompensating for padding on one side is a "hack". If you really want to use the font I would certainly trade using a nicer font and having to add an extra px of padding to the bottom, then settling for something maybe not as nice

Comment: I've changed to Roboto, because its a common font, but the problem persists.